# Get property of the fields generated by query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to get the property/metadata of the fields generated in a query in SQL Server? like in Oracle(or at least like in Toad)? How?

For example, I have t1 and t2. t1 has (id int, name varchar(30), desc varchar(50))
while t2 has (id int, startDate date, endDate date, updby int) then I have a query:

```
select t1.name, t1.desc, t2.startDate t2.endDate
from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Now, I want to get the property/metadata of the fields as in:

```
name varchar(30),
desc varchar(50),
startDate date,
endDate date
```

Such that it corresponds to their origin tables.

Note that I have tried it on Toad (Oracle) using Ctrl+Shift+F9 command shortcut.

Comment: try alt+F1 key combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT syscolumns.name,systypes.name,syscolumns.isnullable, syscolumns.length  
FROM syscolumns, systypes  
WHERE syscolumns.xusertype = systypes.xusertype  
AND syscolumns.id = object_id('YourTableName')
```

Result:

```
name        name    isnullable  length
Id           int        0        4
Name        nchar       1        20
StartDate   date        1        3
EndDate     date        1        3
```

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008,that query run in SSMS.Which object not recognize?

Comment: Oh, I see. So I need SSMS?

Comment: Yes,your can try it.Good luck!

Comment: @ChristianMark no error check in ssms it will give the results

Answer (score 0):

If you are just running your query in SSMS, then that meta data is available in the sys.columns system view. Just search for the particular column by name and object_id (usually the id of the table).

Comment: Can elaborate more about SSMS?

Comment: SSMS is SQL Server Management Studio. It's the tool you usually to run ad-hoc queries and also perform management tasks for SQL Server. (Kind of like Toad). It is included with the full version of SQL Server - there's also a version available for SQL Server Express.